# add UIImage in CALayer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer, subview

I must add a UIImageView as subview of MapView. To do this I created a layer above the MapView. In this layer I want to put my image, but I get a white rectangle and nothing else. My image is not visible.

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //......

    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        layer.bounds = CGRectMake(self.mapView.bounds.origin.x,
                                  self.mapView.bounds.origin.y, 80, 300);
    }
    else
    {
        layer.bounds = CGRectMake(self.mapView.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.mapView.frame.origin.y, 150, 700);
    }

    layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    //the name is correct but  in the output the image is not visible

    [[self.mapView layer] addSublayer:layer];
    [layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This is a general answer for the sake of future viewers. It is based on the question title rather than the details of the original question.

## How to add a UIImage to a CALayer

You can add an image to a view's `layer` simply by using its `contents` property:

```
myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
```

- Note that the `UIImage` needs to be converted to a `CGImage`.

If you wish to add the image in its own layer, you can do it like this:

```
let myLayer = CALayer()
let myImage = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
myLayer.frame = myView.bounds
myLayer.contents = myImage
myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

## Modifying the appearance

The above code produces a view like this. The light blue is the `UIView` and the dark blue star is the `UIImage`.

[image]

As you can see, though, it looks pixelated. This is because the `UIImage` is smaller than the `UIView` so it is being scaled to fill the view, which is the default it you don't specify anything else.

The examples below show variations on the layer's `contentsGravity` property. The code looks like this:

```
myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
myView.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop
myView.layer.isGeometryFlipped = true
```

In iOS, you may want to set the [`isGeometryFlipped` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/geometryFlipped) to `true` if you are doing anything with top or bottom gravity, otherwise it will be the opposite of what you expect. (Only the gravity is flipped vertically, not the content rendering. If you are having trouble with the content being flipped, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407999/3681880).)

There are two `UIView` examples below for every `contentsGravity` setting, one view is larger than the `UIImage` and the other is smaller. This way you can see the effects of the scaling and gravity.

**`kCAGravityResize`**

This is the default.

[image]

**`kCAGravityResizeAspect`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityResizeAspectFill`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityCenter`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityTop`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityBottom`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityLeft`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityRight`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityTopLeft`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityTopRight`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityBottomLeft`**

[image]

**`kCAGravityBottomRight`**

[image]

## Related

- [Content mode property of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32151862/3681880)
- [Drawing a `UIImage` in `drawRect` with `CGContextDrawImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407999/3681880)
- [CALayer Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples)

Comment: Great answer. But how do you do kCAGravityResizeAspectFill and kCAGravityTop at the same time?

Comment: adjusting the contentsRect to the right ratio does the trick. Another option is to use an UIImageView as UIView maskView.

Comment: fantastic tutorial buddy @suragch   Took me forever to find out that .gravity is where you set aspect fit/fill/etc.   Note that interestingly the current Apple doco is plain wrong, it doesn't mention those options! the main doco page only mentions resize/center/flipped.  Weird!

Comment: addition for everyone: layer.contentsGravity = view.contentMode

Comment: To prevent the image from being rendered x2 or x3 times bigger than it should, you should set the CALayer's scale to match the screen's scale: layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale

Answer (score 47):

it has to be

```
layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"].CGImage;
```

You can only put a CGImage into a layer, not an UIImage directly.

Answer (score 9):

I removed

```
 [layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

I do not know why, but it works!

Comment: I guess the setNeedsDisplay made the layer to redraw the content and so deleting the image.

Comment: Plus one for this. It definitely triggers a redraw (what I thought it needed), but it throws away `content` before redrawing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the frame of the CALayer properly, because the default is CGRectZero.

Answer (score 3):

## 2020, full simple examples

In this example, the image is simply the size of the overall view:

```
class ImageyView: UIView {
    
    private lazy var im: CALayer = {
        let l = CALayer()
        l.contents = UIImage(named: "some_background")?.cgImage
        l.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(l)
        return l
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        im.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

In this example it's a Button, with small icon you're adding at the top left:

```
class BroadcastButton: UIButton {
    
    private lazy var im: CALayer = {
        let l = CALayer()
        l.contents = UIImage(named: "your_icon")?.cgImage
        l.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(l)
        return l
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        im.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2),
             size: CGSize(width: 14, height: 14))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage*

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer. Even if your answer is a complete solution, the asker will learn more if you take the time to explain what your code does, and how you came up with it.

Comment: @Jolta I don't think there is any more details to add to OP's answer. This is the code.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This should be a comment, but I lost few hours, so I'm making it a stand alone answer.</sub>

I was doing:

```
myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "star")
```

can you find what the problem is? Because `contents` is of type `Any` then this just compiles fine. But the correct code is:

```
myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "star").cgImage
```