# Draw on UIImageView without replacing its original image iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-graphics

This code make changes to the imageview, but it replaces its original image. I need to edit on the original image not to replace it.

```
- (void)drawShapes {
    //NSLog(@"In drawShapes!");

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.planView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for(myShape *i in _collection) {
        [self drawShapesSubroutine:i contextRef:context];
        if(i.selected == true) {
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]);
            float num[] = {6.0, 6.0};
            CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, num, 2);

            CGRect rectangle;
            [self drawShapeSelector:i selectorRect: &rectangle];
            CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);


            //tapped = true;
        }
    }

    if(!skipDrawingCurrentShape && (selectedIndex == -1)) {
        [self drawShapesSubroutine:_currentShape contextRef:context];
    }
    self.planView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

When I remove this line:

```
self.planView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

The image doesn't disappear but also doesn't draw. I need to draw without removing the original photo.

Comment: how r  u calling the drawshapes ?

Comment: i am calling it like this
[self drawShapes];

Comment: you cant do imagview.image because, it will replace the old image with new one. If you are planning to draw something new on the image view, try to add sublayer on the imageview

Comment: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() this returns an image 
it refusers to do this : 
[self.planView.layer addSublayer: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

Comment: convert your image into cgiimage and add it to layer

Comment: which image 
this ? UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
or this self.planView.image

Comment: you should convert UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() into UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage;

Comment: [self.planView.layer addSublayer: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage];
this crashes

Comment: you need to create a CALayer and add your CGI image to the layer.contents and use that layer as sub layer

Comment: see this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272512/add-uiimage-in-calayer

Answer (score 6):

You cant do `imagview.image` because, it will replace the old image with new one. If you are planning to draw something new on the image view, try to add sublayer on the `imageview`.

convert your image into cgiimage and add it to layer.you should convert `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` into `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage`

you need to create a `CALayer` and add your CGI image to the `layer.contents` and use that layer as sub layer

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.contents = (id)UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage;
```

and do this:

```
[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Comment: for my task i won't make addsublayer except for the first time , and keep editing that layer

Comment: the CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
line gives linker error

Comment: maybe you should add QuartzCore framework to your project.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ECS189DrawingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: did u try adding quartzcore ?

Comment: i have included it and nothing changed i don't know why 
here is the link to that simple project , the class named ECS189DrawingViewController.m
https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=DrawingApp-master.zip

Comment: i will look into it. I couldnt see the file at the link you provided