# Subview cannot be displayed in the camera preview in IOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, avfoundation

I use `AVFoundation` framework to capture and display the camera video preview and it works. Now, I want add my own `UIImageView` on the top of camera preview, here are some fragments of my code.

```
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            previewLayer!.frame = previewView.bounds
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 130,y: 320,width: 60,height: 30))
            imageView.image  = UIImage(named:"scanbutton.png")                
            previewView.addSubview(imageView)

            self.captureSession!.startRunning()
```

The "scanbutton.png" image file is in the project folder.

The `UIImageView` cannot be displayed. Can anyone tell what's wrong, thanks.

Comment: To clarify, do you see the image on your screen? but not in the recording?

Comment: I cannot see the image on the screen.

Comment: try changing previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!) to previewView.insertSublayer(previewLayer, atIndex: 0)

Comment: still cannot display. I wonder if the UIImageView is empty. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272512/add-uiimage-in-calayer, I only add sublayer of my own image like this:                 'let myImage = UIImage(named: "scanbutton.png")?.CGImage;
                let myLayer = CALayer()
                myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 130,y: 320,width: 60,height: 30)
                myLayer.contents = myImage
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)'  It doesn't display anything.