# Applying gradient to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cagradientlayer

I want to apply color gradient(from top to bottom) to an image named 'newspaperImage'. This is my code using swift language.

```
@IBOutlet weak var newspaperImage: UIImageView!

func imageGradient(){
    let newspaperview = UIView(frame: newspaperImage.frame)
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = newspaperview.bounds
    let startColor = UIColor(red: 30, green: 113, blue: 79, alpha: 0).cgColor
    let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor]
    newspaperview.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    newspaperImage.addSubview(newspaperview)
    newspaperImage.bringSubviewToFront(newspaperview)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageGradient()
}
```

After running, I find it doesn't work at all. Where's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810839/drawing-gradient-over-image-in-ios

Comment: `UIColor` Parameters are specified as values between 0-1 (normalised values of 255)

Comment: @MadProgrammer It has nothing to so with Parameters. If I change code to `let startColor =UIColor.white.cgColor` , it still doesn't work.

Comment: Solve one problem at a time ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703220/10505343 will help you to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

First lets start with `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` expects the parameters to be normalised values of 0-1.

So...

```
let startColor = UIColor(red: 30, green: 113, blue: 79, alpha: 0).cgColor
```

should be

```
let startColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 113/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 0).cgColor
```

Next, I took your basic code and dumped into Playground

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Miho_Small.png")

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = imageView.bounds
let startColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 113/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 0).cgColor
let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor]
imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

imageView
```

And it generated...

[image: Surprise]

Okay, that's not what I was expecting, but it's not entirely unsurprising.  The `CALayer` is been painted over the top of the image, because the image is been painted by the `UIView`'s `draw` function.

Okay, so how can we fix it?  With out going to the extend of making a new images and painting the gradient and image into it, you could make use of a "background" `UIView`, onto which the layer and `UIImageView` are applied...

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Miho_Small.png")

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
imageView.backgroundColor = nil

let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = backgroundView.bounds
let startColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 113/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 0).cgColor
let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor]
backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)

backgroundView
```

which generates...

[image: Better]

And, that's probably more along the lines of what you're trying to achieve...at a guess

> :(, the two views can not be overlapped

I don't "overlap", so to speak, I add the `UIImageView` onto the `backgroundView`, which contains the `CALayer`.  Remember, the view's `frame` is relative to it's parent's coordinate space.

In almost all cases, I prefer to use auto layout, and I prefer to use story boards, but those are difficult to make int an answer, so I've done it by hand for this example...

[image: Example]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let image = UIImage(named: "Miho_Small.png")

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.backgroundColor = nil

    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
    backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = backgroundView.bounds
    let startColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 113/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 0).cgColor
    let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor]
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)

    view.addSubview(backgroundView)

    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    backgroundView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    backgroundView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundView,
                                                    attribute: .width,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: nil,
                                                    attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                                    multiplier: 1.0,
                                                    constant: 250))
    backgroundView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundView,
                                                    attribute: .width,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: backgroundView,
                                                    attribute: .height,
                                                    multiplier: 1.0,
                                                    constant: 0))


  }


}
```

For what it's worth, you can checkout the project I used to test the code from [GitHub - TestCALayerGradientAndImageOverlay](https://github.com/RustyKnight/TestCALayerGradientAndImageOverlay)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I have another problem :(, the two views can not be overlapped. You can see my screen shot image in the link below. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkKaE.png)

Comment: I didn’t overlay them, I added both to a base view - personally, I’d use autolayout to pin them to the edges. You need to make sure the frames of the child views match the bounds of the parent view

Comment: Hey! Is there a way to use gradient to change only the alpha value and not add any color to the gradient? Like the image should fade out from bottom to top?