# Creating a custom UI view class to use as a map annotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, mapbox

I created a custom UIView using storyboard. I don't want this at the coordinates that it is in in my storyboard, but I want to be able to reuse it throughout my app at different locations on a map [like this](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/default-callout/). I also want to be able to update the text in there at the users request, and the number in there should increase whenever the green button is clicked. I also want to [customize the image below it, like I learned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510763/ios-dev-using-a-custom-image-for-the-user-annotation-in-mapbox/) so that the user annotation has an image and this callout above it. The callout would only be there if the user has posted some text. It would look like this.

[image]

My [previously linked example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/default-callout/) uses a method called setcenter to place the coordinate in the middle of the annotation, but it looks like the [MGLMapView documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/maps/4.1.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(py)centerCoordinate) and [uiview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) documentation contain at most a setcentercoordinate function, so this is why I tried creating the annotation in storyboard instead of coding it in swift, because I didn't know how to add things to the annotation. It also doesn't look like that example show's how to constrain views to the bottom corners, like I did with my buttons (There is one view for the rocket and person button, and one view for the arrow button and the number).

Because I want to update the text field and that number(which is a label), I don't know if storyboard is the best idea to create this. I also don't know if I can use a storyboard object at a dynamic location, and create multiple of them throughout the map

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your questions?

Comment: @Magnas I want to create a custom annotation to use as a speech bubble. Much like my first link, but I want it took look like that one I created in storyboard, with the addition of some type of image or face below the speech bubble.

Comment: you can use a xib file to create your view or whatever you want and then instead of using the IBOutlets of your elements in your view controller using that xib file