# Setting content mode for something besides UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, contentmode

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32151862/3681880) shows the various effects of setting the [content mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) of a `UIImageView`.

Since `UIView` also has a content mode setting in the Interface Builder, I want to know why setting it doesn't affect any subviews that are in it.

Here is an example that I tried. The blue view is a `UIView` and the yellow view is a `UILabel`.

[image]

But if I set the mode to Top for the `UIView`, the label just stays in the same place.

[image]

Does content mode only work for `UIImageViews`? If it doesn't work for `UIViews`, why is it even there?

Comment: Already have question and answer here :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827710/what-type-of-contents-uiviewcontentmode-mode-refers-to][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827710/what-type-of-contents-uiviewcontentmode-mode-refers-to

Comment: @anhtu, thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contentMode` modifies only the views' contents and not its subviews'. So if you have a custom view and you draw something in its `drawRect` then you will see that it gets changed every time you change the `contentMode` of your view.

Now in case of `UIImageView`, the image is actually the content of the view (which is internally drawn in its `drawRect`), so you can see the image changing when you change the `contentMode` of your UIImageView.